# Array category subcategory

Tags: arrays, perl

I have this category and subcategory table.

The field that has the value `NULL` for `parent_id` is a category, and the ones that use `parent_id` are subcategories.

My tree view has subcategories assigned only to categories, so no subcategories for subcategories.

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+
| id | name                | parent_id |
+----+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 | Laptop              |      NULL |
|  2 | TV                  |      NULL |
|  3 | Tablet & Mobile     |      NULL |
|  4 | PC                  |      NULL |
|  5 | Laptops             |         1 |
|  6 | Laptop accessories  |         1 |
|  7 | TV accessories      |         2 |
```

If I do a `SELECT *` and spice it with a `while` I get the following array.

```
'category' => [
              {
                'name' => 'Laptop',
                'id' => '1',
                'parent_id' => undef
              },
              {
                'name' => 'TV',
                'id' => '2',
                'parent_id' => undef
              },
              {
                'name' => 'Table & mobile',
                'id' => '3',
                'parent_id' => undef
              },
              {
                'name' => 'PC',
                'id' => '4',
                'parent_id' => undef
              },
              {
                'name' => 'Laptops',
                'id' => '5',
                'parent_id' => '1'
              },
              {
                'name' => 'Laptop accessories ',
                'id' => '6',
                'parent_id' => '1'
              },
              {
                'name' => 'TV accessories',
                'id' => '7',
                'parent_id' => '2'
              }
```

The structure I'm looking for should look like this.

```
category 1
-- subcategory 1.1
-- subcategory 1.2
category 2
-- subcategory 2.1
```

What I get now looks like

```
category 1
subcategory 1.1
category 2
subcategory 1.2
subcategory 2.1
```

Comment: show what you have tried.  in your desired structure, are subcategories (and the main parentless categories) ordered by id or name or orderless?

Comment: Without seeing the code, we can't tell you what you're doing wrong. The data output looks like it's all there.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Sorry, I wasn't to specific. The data output is not the problem. I just displayed what I have so far, I'l edit and add the `while` that I used to go through the records after the query. As for the code that I worked for the new structure, some attempts were in perl, some in vue.js, some in sql. When I was sure I failed I deleted and tried another route, but after seeing what @choroba posted, I wasn't even near his answer which was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @John: Hint: **choroba's** post isn't what you want either. Spraying your attempts over Perl, Vue, and SQL in the hope of seeing the right result will leave you cornered with so many bugs you don't know where to look. You don't even tell us what database engine or HTTP server you're using. Is this a CGI app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %struct = (category => [
    {
        'name' => 'Laptop',
        'id' => '1',
        'parent_id' => undef
    },
    {
        'name' => 'TV',
        'id' => '2',
        'parent_id' => undef
    },
    {
        'name' => 'Table & mobile',
        'id' => '3',
        'parent_id' => undef
    },
    {
        'name' => 'PC',
        'id' => '4',
        'parent_id' => undef
    },
    {
        'name' => 'Laptops',
        'id' => '5',
        'parent_id' => '1'
    },
    {
        'name' => 'Laptop accessories ',
        'id' => '6',
        'parent_id' => '1'
    },
    {
        'name' => 'TV accessories',
        'id' => '7',
        'parent_id' => '2'
    }
]);


my %tree;
for my $cat (grep ! defined $_->{parent_id}, @{ $struct{category} }) {
    $tree{ $cat->{id} } = $cat;
}

for my $cat (grep defined $_->{parent_id}, @{ $struct{category} }) {
    $tree{ $cat->{parent_id} }{subcat}{ $cat->{id} } = $cat;
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%tree;
```

Comment: Had to research 'grep' first (I'm not that good in perl) but it does exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.